# Show that $ f $ is a content over $ \mathcal{A}:=\{A\subseteq \Omega: A \text{ is counterable or } A^c \text{ is counterable}\} $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ \Omega $ an uncountable set. Consider the $ \sigma $-Alegbra $$ \mathcal{A}:=\{A\subseteq \Omega: A \text{ is countable or } A^c \text{ is countable}\} $$ and the function $ f: \mathcal{A}\to [0,1] $
$$ f(A):=\begin{cases}
0 & A \text{ is countable}\\
1 & A^c \text{ is countable}
\end{cases}. $$

I want to show that $ f $ is a content over $ \mathcal{A} $.

So I take arbitrary disjoint sets $ A,B\in \mathcal{A} $. I have to look at four cases:

1.) $ A $ is countable and $ B $ is countable. Then $ A\cup B $ is countable. It follows $$ f(A\cup B)=0=0+0=f(A)+f(B). $$

2.) $ A $ is countable and $ B^c $ is countable. Then $ B = (B^c)^c $ is uncountable such that $ A\cup B $ is uncountable. Furthermore it is $ (A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c\subseteq B^c $ which means $ (A\cup B)^c $ is countable. It follows $$ f(A\cup B)=1=0+1=f(A)+f(B).
 $$

3.) $ A^c $ is countable and $ B $ is countable. Then $ A = (A^c)^c $ is uncountable such that $ A\cup B $ is uncountable. Furthermore it is $ (A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c\subseteq A^c $ which means $ (A\cup B)^c $ is countable. It follows $$ f(A\cup B)=1=1+0=f(A)+f(B).
 $$

4.) $ A^c $ is countable and $ B^c $ is countable. Then $ A $ and $ B $ are uncountable and it follows $ A\cup B $ is uncountable. So $ (A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c\subseteq A^c $ is countable. But then $$ f(A\cup B)=1\neq 1+1=f(A)+f(B). $$

What went wrong in the last case 4?

Comment: Do you mean "countable" ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typos.

Comment: Is there anyone to help?